# how to find out the cpu "code name" (architecture family)?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-architecture

I get access to some xeon machines for checking performance. I want to find out what architecture they are using such as Haswell, Sandybridge , Ivybridge. Is there a command to find this out?

Comment: `/proc/cpuinfo` actually gives the model name like `Intel (R) blah blah blah GHz`, you should google it directly.

Comment: I was asking for architecture family

Comment: I don't think the “architecture family” is reported, they're just commercial names. You get the model name in `/proc/cpuinfo`, I think it's up to you to translate that into the corresponding family name.

Comment: @Ijustwanttocode You have to use some kind of table to look up those commercial names.

Answer (score 69):

It's a bit of a cheap workaround but you could get that info from `gcc` !
I'll explain : `gcc` is able to optimize binaries for each subarch with the `-march` option. Moreover, it is able to detect yours and automatically optimize for your machine with `-march=native`

Assuming so, you just have to call `gcc` with `march=native` and ask it what flags it would use :
in short

```
gcc -march=native -Q --help=target|grep march
```

for me it gives

```
-march=                               bdver1
```

since my pc runs with an amd buldozer processor

Comment: your solution answers the question. It works for me.

Comment: This doesn't work for me as it returns `broadwell` instead of `kabylake`. This is probably because my version of gcc doesn't distinguish those two families when generating assembly.

Comment: gcc8 can identify skylake as such whereas gcc5 identifies as broadwell, indeed.

Answer (score 52):

## This data is stored in PMU_NAME, just type:

```
cat /sys/devices/cpu/caps/pmu_name
haswell
```

Comment: This is really the easiest solution and I believe the best answer, as it does not require any additional commands (like gcc or pup) to be installed and it gives a clean output of just the name of the microarchitecture, which can be used directly in a script.

Comment: This gives `skylake` on my machine, whereas Intel's site says it is `kaby lake` : https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97185/intel-core-i7-7700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html says

Comment: Note that this file does not exist on AMD machines.

Comment: @Tyilo: Similar for me: an i7-8565U is reported as "skylake" whereas Intel says "Whiskey Lake".

Comment: What this returns is I believe the gcc/clang march/mtune compiler flags. For example: march=skylake  -mtune=skylake is from comet lake. https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/comet_lake inxi -Cx will attempt to show microarchitecture, but it uses a manually compiled table to generate the microarchitecture name, which can sometimes be ambiguous. Which means, always use the latest git inxi if you want this data to reflect latest known IDs and matches.

Comment: Even on Intel processors this file might not exist.

Comment: There might be few reasons for that, CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS or (CONFIG_HW_PERF_EVENTS) needs to be enable, your kernel should not be to old. More info can be found in: /usr/src/linux/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-event_source-devices-caps. /usr/src/linux/tools/perf/Documentation/perf.data-file-format.txt keep more info about pmu_name. (guest systems may be another reason for not showing the pmu_name on "recent" intel cpus)

Answer (score 15):

You probably can't because those are marketing names for commercial sale, not the "technical" name.

You can, however, obtain what you need from dmidecode and then visit http://ark.intel.com (for your Xeon processor) to determine the commercial family.

```
[root@mediasrv ~]# dmidecode|grep -i intel
        Socket Designation: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
        Manufacturer: Intel
        Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
```

From that output, I could visit Intel's ark website and search for the 3770 CPU, which would tell me I have an Ivy Bridge chip.

Comment: To do it automated with a script i would use dmidecode or /proc/cpuinfo and combine it with grep or awk or perl and the printable version of the xeon cpu list on wikipedia which you get with curl or wget: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors&printable=yes

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** This script doesn't work anymore. Intel's search URL has changed.

Below is a bash script that automatically finds the architecture code name for your CPU using `/proc/cpuinfo` and https://ark.intel.com/.
To work it requires that you have [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) installed.

Running the code on my computer I get the following result:

```
$ ./intel_codename
Processor name: i7-7700HQ
Kaby Lake
```

---

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then
    modelname=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | head -1)
    if ! grep Intel <<<"$modelname" > /dev/null; then
        echo "You don't seem to have an Intel processor" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    name=$(sed 's/.*\s\(\S*\) CPU.*/\1/' <<<"$modelname")
    echo "Processor name: $name" >&2
else
    name=$1
fi

links=($(curl --silent "https://ark.intel.com/search?q=$name" | pup '.result-title a attr{href}'))

results=${#links[@]}
if [[ $results == 0 ]]; then
    echo "No results found" >&2
    exit 1
fi

link=${links[0]}
if [[ $results != 1 ]]; then
    echo "Warning: $results results found" >&2
    echo "Using: $link" >&2
fi

url="https://ark.intel.com$link"
codename=$(curl --silent "$url" | pup '.CodeNameText .value text{}' | xargs | sed 's/Products formerly //')

echo "$codename"
```

Comment: It works and does what @erik suggested!

Comment: my /proc/cpuinfo contains "model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.00GHz", so this script doesn't work

Comment: A disadvantage is, that it requires 'pup' to be installed. After installing pup, it still fails without completing the script. Tested on GRML in 2019.

Comment: It is indeed true that this doesn't work anymore. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

On the cloud none of the above answers work for me.   I have a model name of "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.00GHz", dmidecode tells me that Google made the processors, et cetera.

/proc/cpuinfo "cpu family" and "model" help quite a bit.  They're unique for almost all combinations and can be looked up on https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/cpuid.   However family 6 model 85 is both skylake and cascade lake.

Answer (score 0):

Attempted to fix the script that @Tyilo posted earlier.  The updated version is below.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then
    modelname=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | head -1)
    if ! grep Intel <<<"$modelname" > /dev/null; then
        echo "You don't seem to have an Intel processor" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    name=$(sed 's/.*CPU\s\(.*\)\s\(@\).*/\1/' <<<"$modelname")
    echo "Processor name: $name" >&2
    name=${name// /'%20'}
else
    name=$1
fi

links=($(curl --silent "https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/search.html?_charset_=UTF-8&q=$name" | pup '#FormRedirectUrl attr{value}'))

results=${#links[@]}
if [[ $results == 0 ]]; then
    echo "No results found" >&2
    exit 1
fi

link=${links[0]}
if [[ $results != 1 ]]; then
    echo "Warning: $results results found" >&2
    echo "Using: $link" >&2
fi

url="https://ark.intel.com$link"
codename=$(curl --silent "$url" | pup 'span[data-key="CodeNameText"] text{}' | xargs | sed 's/Products formerly //')

echo "$codename"
```

Running the updated script on my server I get the following result:

```
$ ./intel_codename 
Processor name: E3-1225 v5
Skylake
```

Not an expert at all.  Just learned how to use curl and pup in the last hour or so.  Didn't test it on others except my own machine.

**Update:**
Did some more testing.  The script should work for **Xeon** Processor family.  However it breaks (showing No results found) if Intel Ark database query returns multiple results.  For example for Xeon Platinum 8260, it will return 8260 and all its variants such as 8260M.  Also, if the name (processor numbering) happens to be used in other products or key data fields, multiple results will be returned from the query and the script won't find the result.  It also breaks for those version 0 processor, such as Xeon E5-2690 0.

For Intel **Core** Processor family (i7, i5, etc), you need to replace **sed** command with the original one by @Tyilo, see below.

```
name=$(sed 's/.*\s\(\S*\) CPU.*/\1/' <<<"$modelname")
```

Again, if query returns multiple results.  This simple script won't be able to parse correct and yields No results found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working in server land. My script works on at least more recent servers.
To differentiate between skylake and cascade lake servers is not pretty... it uses the /proc/cpuinfo 'model name' field to tease out skylake vs cascade lake.

```
#!/bin/bash
# cascade lake 2nd gen stuff from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/processors/xeon/2nd-gen-xeon-scalable-spec-update.html
# 2nd gen xeon scalable cpus: cascade lake sku is 82xx, 62xx, 52xx, 42xx 32xx W-32xx  from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/processors/xeon/2nd-gen-xeon-scalable-spec-update.html
# skylake 1st gen stuff from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/scalable/xeon-scalable-spec-update.html
# 1st gen xeon scalable cpus: 81xx, 61xx, 51xx, 81xxT, 61xxT 81xxF, 61xxF, 51xx, 41xx, 31xx, 51xxT 41xxT, 51xx7, 
CPU_NAME=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '
  function decode_fam_mod(vndor, fam, mod, mod_nm) {
    if (vndor == "GenuineIntel") {
      # cpuid tables from https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/cpuid
      dcd[1,1]="Ice Lake";              dcd[1,2] ="Family 6 Model 108";
      dcd[2,1]="Ice Lake";              dcd[2,2] ="Family 6 Model 106";
      dcd[3,1]="Cascade Lake/Skylake";  dcd[3,2] ="Family 6 Model 85"; # 06_55h  Intel always does the hex fam_model
      dcd[4,1]="Broadwell";             dcd[4,2] ="Family 6 Model 79"; # 06_4fh
      dcd[5,1]="Broadwell";             dcd[5,2] ="Family 6 Model 86"; # 06_56h
      dcd[6,1]="Haswell";               dcd[6,2] ="Family 6 Model 63"; # 06_3fh
      dcd[7,1]="Ivy Bridge";            dcd[7,2] ="Family 6 Model 62";
      dcd[8,1]="Sandy Bridge";          dcd[8,2] ="Family 6 Model 45"; # 06_2dh
      dcd[9,1]="Westmere";              dcd[9,2] ="Family 6 Model 44";
      dcd[10,1]="EX";                   dcd[10,2]="Family 6 Model 47";
      dcd[11,1]="Nehalem";              dcd[11,2]="Family 6 Model 46";
      dcd[12,1]="Lynnfield";            dcd[12,2]="Family 6 Model 30";
      dcd[13,1]="Bloomfield, EP, WS";   dcd[13,2]="Family 6 Model 26";
      dcd[14,1]="Penryn";               dcd[14,2]="Family 6 Model 29";
      dcd[15,1]="Harpertown, QC, Wolfdale, Yorkfield";  dcd[15,2]="Family 6 Model 23";
      str = "Family " fam " Model " mod;
      #printf("str= %s\n", str);
      res=" ";
      for(k=1;k <=15;k++) { if (dcd[k,2] == str) {res=dcd[k,1];break;}}
      if (k == 3) {
        # so Cooper Lake/Cascade Lake/SkyLake)
        if (match(mod_nm, / [86543]2[0-9][0-9]/) > 0) { res="Cascade Lake";} else
        if (match(mod_nm, / [86543]1[0-9][0-9]/) > 0) { res="Skylake";}
      }
      return res;
    }
  }
  /^vendor_id/ {
    vndr=$(NF);
  }
  /^cpu family/ {
    fam=$(NF);
  }
  /^model/ {
    if ($2 == ":") {
      mod=$(NF);
    }
  }
  /^model name/ {
#model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz
    n=split($0, arr, ":");
    mod_nm = arr[2];
    #printf("vndr= %s, fam= %s, mod= %s, mod_nm= %s\n", vndr, fam, mod, mod_nm);
    cpu_name=decode_fam_mod(vndr, fam, mod, mod_nm);
    printf("%s\n", cpu_name);
    exit;
  }
'`
echo "cpu uarch= $CPU_NAME"
```

This doesn't handle the client cpus... but it should be relatively straight forward to take the client cpuid info from [WikiChip](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/WikiChip) and expand the list.

Answer (score 0):

I have an AMD processor. This command helped me:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 4
```

In particular,  here's what you need I think:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 4 | grep -i family
```

My result is:

```
Family: Zen
Signature: Family 23, Model 24, Stepping 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The "code name" isn't stored anywhere that's why it's not possible to get it via tools like `dmidecode`, `lscpu`, `lshw`, `/proc/cpuinfo` etc. For that, as some of the answers here point out, you'd need a database.
The only Linux/BSD app that I know of, that does that, is [`cpu-x`](https://github.com/TheTumultuousUnicornOfDarkness/CPU-X). It has its own [*database*](https://github.com/TheTumultuousUnicornOfDarkness/CPU-X/blob/master/src/databases.h) and it will print (among other things) the CPU "code name" e.g.

```
        ***** Processor *****
          Vendor: AMD
       Code Name: Ryzen 7 (Renoir)
         Package: FP6
      Technology: 7 nm
         Voltage: 1,210 V
   Specification: AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics
          Family: 0xF
    Disp. Family: 0x17
           Model: 0x0
     Disp. Model: 0x60
        Stepping: 1
          .........
```

Run `cpu-x --help` for more options (curses, gui, etc.)