# How can I find the human readable name for a CPU?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, google-cloud, lscpu

I need to know the name of the CPU used in a GKE cluster I have launched.  The `gcloud` command has a `--min-cpu-platform` option, but my understanding is that is the minimum and I may get a later CPU type.  When I log into the node and run `lscpu` and/or `lshw` the `CPU Family`, `Model`, and `Stepping` are given, but I have been unable to find a way to convert these values into something like "Ice Lake", or "Cascade Lake", etc. which is what I need.

This is not a duplicate of [how to find out intel architecture family from command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230634/how-to-find-out-intel-architecture-family-from-command-line) as either the commands are not available on GKE nodes, or do not produce the information I am looking for.  I need a way to lookup the name given the CPU family, model, and stepping values provided by `lscpu`.  Neither ark.intel.com nor Wikipedia seem to have this information.

Comment: What output do you get from these commands or other commands in the dupe?

Comment: Ice Lake, Kaby Lake etc are "code names", as I wrote [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/765052/22142) they're not stored on the system and you can only get them via a conversion table, whether it's online or local...

Comment: @muru the main problem is that since these are Google managed machines (GKE) with minimal OS installations many of the commands and/or files are not available or don't return useful information. For example `dmidecode` claims the CPU, bios, etc are all from "Google Inc". I would like to avoid having to connect to a node to `sudo apt install` software and was hoping there would be some sort of conversion table somewhere I could reference, but that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `lscpu` command you mention, `lspci`, `dmidecode` or `less /proc/cpuinfo` might provide additional clues to aid your search.

```
$ lspci | grep -i bridge
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DMI3 Registers (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f9)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f9)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C621 Series Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 09)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: ASPEED Technology, Inc. AST1150 PCI-to-PCI Bridge (rev 04)
17:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A (rev 04)
17:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port C (rev 04)
17:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port D (rev 04)
3a:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A (rev 04)
85:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port C (rev 04)
85:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port D (rev 04)
ae:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A (rev 04)
ae:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port C (rev 04)
# dmidecode -s processor-version
Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6130 CPU @ 2.10GHz
Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6130 CPU @ 2.10GHz
```

If that still doesn't help, you may have to resort to finding out whatever you can about the processor family and version, and then doing some web searching to find out what the code name is.

Depending on what OS the system is running, some other helpful commands might be:

```
$ grep -i cpu /var/run/dmesg.boot

$ pciconf -lv
```

Comment: Sadly, either those commands are not available on GKE nodes, or don't produce the information I am looking for.  Unfortunately I have not been able to find anything on the web that allows me to lookup the name from the CPU Family, model , and stepping information I get from `lscpu` et al.